# Admob Reward Video GADRewardBasedVideoAd in Objective c IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ads

I'm trying to reward a user for watching a video with AdMob.For example Every X searches, the user should be shown videos of showing them the results.I don't have any idea about Video Ads.Can you help me? please see the code below:

```
[GADRewardBasedVideoAd sharedInstance].delegate = self;
GADRequest *request1 = [GADRequest request];

  request1.testDevices = kGADSimulatorID;
[[GADRewardBasedVideoAd sharedInstance] loadRequest:[GADRequest request]
                                       withAdUnitID:@"ca-app-pub-4719922286387557/6283056409"];
if ([[GADRewardBasedVideoAd sharedInstance] isReady]) {
    [[GADRewardBasedVideoAd sharedInstance] presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
```